# repeating decimals and carmichael function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, totient-function, carmichael-function

Wikipedia states [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Totient_rule):

> **For an arbitrary integer $n$ the length $\lambda (n)$ of the repetend
>   of $1/n$** divides $\phi (n)$, where $\phi$ is the totient function.

In the next section, it defines $\lambda(n)$ as [Carmichael's Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Computing_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000000A-QINU%60%22'%7F_with_Carmichael's_theorem):

> λ(n) is the least common multiple of the λ of each of its prime power
>   factors:
>
> $\lambda (n)=lcm (\lambda (p_{1}^{r_{1}}),\lambda
> > (p_{2}^{r_{2}}),\dots, \lambda (p_{k}^{r_{k}}))$

1. **I want to know if the two different functions symbolized by $\lambda(n)$ are the same.** If so, it seems to me that I can use Carmichaels Function as a generic method to write  an algorithm that determines if $1/n$ repeats, and if it does I want it to give an accurate length of the repetend.
2. **If they are the same, is the article correct in its statement that $n$ is totally arbitrary?** In other words, can I use this function in general?

*I am not a pure math guy. I am simply trying to apply theorems I am reading online to solve a problem. Please keep that context in mind when you answer :)*

So far my algorithm determines repetition, but it appears that most of my lengths are wrong. This could be a bug in my code, or it could be my misunderstanding of the wikipedia article. Here are some of my results for $n \in \{2,\dots 11,\}$

```
Fraction: 1/2
factors of 2 are [2]
1/2 is not repeating


Fraction: 1/3
factors of 3 are [3]
1/3 is repeating:  0.3333333333333333
length of repetition is 2


Fraction: 1/4
factors of 4 are [2, 2]
1/4 is not repeating


Fraction: 1/5
factors of 5 are [5]
1/5 is not repeating


Fraction: 1/6
factors of 6 are [2, 3.0]
1/6 is repeating:  0.16666666666666666
length of repetition is 2


Fraction: 1/7
factors of 7 are [7]
1/7 is repeating:  0.14285714285714285
length of repetition is 6.0


Fraction: 1/8
factors of 8 are [2, 2, 2]
1/8 is not repeating


Fraction: 1/9
factors of 9 are [3, 3]
1/9 is repeating:  0.1111111111111111
length of repetition is 6.0


Fraction: 1/10
factors of 10 are [2, 5.0]
1/10 is not repeating


Fraction: 1/11
factors of 11 are [11]
1/11 is repeating:  0.09090909090909091
length of repetition is 10.0
```

Comment: $\lambda$ means different (but related) things in the two parts of the article

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Dang, that's what I was afraid of. Is there a way to get to where I am trying to go with this? Or should I scrap my algorithm and start over?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545702/the-reciprocal-of-many-prime-numbers-p-in-base-10-have-a-set-of-repeating-digits) is a related question.  If $\gcd(n,10)=1,$ then the length of the repetend will divide the Carmichael function but could be less

Comment: As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/140643/242) the period is the order of $10$ modulo the denominator (in lowest terms). That post links to algorithms to compute the order.